# Problem on Centre of Mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, mass

> If a block of mass smaller than that of a wedge is placed on top, and the system is released from rest, how much would the wedge move by, when the block slides and reaches the ground (Assuming that the wedge is on the ground, and the surfaces being smooth)?

I am aware that in the absence of external forces over a system, the center of mass will not move. If I chose the block and the wedge as a single system, there is gravity that acts to bring the block sliding down. This is the external force. But there is no force on the wedge (gravity and the normal reaction on the wedge by the ground should balance each other).

If this were so, then the centre of mass is not at rest. But then my logic seems to be flawed. Could you please help?

Comment: Why is the question downvoted?

Comment: There is a force on the wedge.  It happens to be an *internal* force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But there is no force on the wedge (gravity and the normal reaction on the wedge by the ground should balance each other).

You are forgetting about Newton's third law. The mass will experience a normal force which is the wedge pushing on the mass perpendicular to the wedge. Therefore, the mass pushes on the wedge perpendicular to the wedge in the opposite direction. This is the force that allows the wedge to move, and thus the center of mass to not move in the horizontal direction.

The center of mass of the system will move in the vertical direction though, since the mass will move downwards but the wedge will not.

Comment: I did not downvote by the way.

Comment: However, what about gravity that acts on the smaller block?

Comment: @KarthikV Oh sorry I was just considering horizontal motion of the COM since you are interested in the horizontal distance covered by the wedge. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Alright. It's clear now. I forgot about the internal force that pushes the wedge. Thanks. I have upvoted the answer.